# Difference between findOrCreate() and upsert() in sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I was reading [over the doc](http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/model/index.html) and it mentioned two ways of doing an upsert: `findOrCreate()` or `upsert()`. I read the descriptions, but I'm still not clear what the difference is.

The `upsert()` goes on to say:

```
Note that the unique index must be defined in your sequelize model and not just in the table. Otherwise you may experience a unique constraint violation, because sequelize fails to identify the row that should be updated.
```

Does this mean `upsert()` explicitly requires I define an `id` UNIQUE primary field in my model? ie:

```
var Something = sequelize.define("Something", { id: { 
                    type: DataTypes.INTEGER, 
                    primaryKey: true, 
                    unique: true, 
                    allowNull: false}});
```

If so, why does `findOrCreate()` not have that restriction?

Can someone explain the use cases for when `findOrCreate()` and `upsert()` should be used, and why `upsert()` has the unique constraint requirement when `findOrCreate()` doesn't seem to need it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`.findOrCreate` will query the database with the parameters you provided, and if there is no match, it will perform an insert operation using those same parameters. Whereas the point of an `.upsert`, is to either update or insert a record. In the case of an update operation, logic dictates that you look for a record based on a unique key, and only once you find this unique record, update its values based on the parameters provided. If you aren't able to find a unique record, only then would you perform an insert.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Hey! Do you know what would happen when there is one Primary/Unique key and one Unique key at the same time in the collection? Is sequelize updates unique key or uses it as a part of select query?

Answer (score 1):

the key difference is Id field. In case of upsert you need the id field. But sometimes, you dont hv the id field. For example when creating a user from an external provider fields say fb, you will not have the id of the user record if it already exists. In this case you will have to use findOrCreate on one of the fields returned by fb like for example email. findOrCreate user where the email is the email returned from fb

Comment: This doesn't always have to be an id, it can be whatever you have set as a key on the table itself. Example: updating a user's information if it's unique by email. If email is a key on the table, then Sequelize can find and update based on that, not the id that exists for the record on the table.